# Typescript variable multi types

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a variable that's declared as two types. Let's take as example this:

```
let foo: number | number[] = null;
```

After that I have an if condition that assign a single number or an array to that variable:

```
if(condition) { 
  foo = 3;
} else {
  foo = [1,2,3];
}
```

The problem starts here. I can't do any action on that variable if I need to check it like if it is an array.

```
if(!!foo.length) { ... }
```

This gives me an error:

> Property 'length' doesn't exists in a type number | number [].

I've red this topic: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards but I was not able to make it works. I've also searched here on SO without finding anything that could have helped me.

I've kinda solved hard-casting it `as any` and it works, but is not an elegant solution.
What am I missing?

```
if(!!(foo as number[]).length) { 
  // this works if foo is an array
} else {
  // this works too and I can just do something like const a:number = foo;
}
```

Comment: Probably a typo? `length`

Comment: @saintlyzero sadly no, I just miss-typed here in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First think type will be as following:

```
let foo: null | number | number[] = null;

// OR 

foo: number | number[];
```

Second, you need to use [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards) to narrow down types to be able to reach the variable, i.e.

```
if(typeof foo === 'number') { 
  foo = 3;
}
else if (typeof foo === 'object' && Array.isArray(var)) {
  foo = [1,2,3];
}
else {
// whatever
}
```

Comment: I don't quite like it but it's working out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if it's an array through Array.isArray(foo) :

```
    if (Array.isArray(foo)){ 
     // array logic
    } else {
      // number logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a typo change `lenght` to `length`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether it is array and after you're sure that it is type of an array, then check its `length`:

```
if(Array.isArray(foo) && foo.length > 0) { 
    ... 
}
```